# IOS Certificate for multiple apps being built at once?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

It seems that we have to get a new certificate every time we switch between apps we're working on and want to test them on our phones. My iPhone developer is stuck with this. Is there a way to keep a certificate for multiple apps? Or a way to have more than 1 certificate active at a time? We've got simultaneous projects going on right now and this is a major issue. I'm guessing there is a simple fix we don't know about? (hoping)

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about provisioning profiles, right? Create an App ID with this format: `com.YourName.*` and then create a provisioning profile from that, and you'll be able to test any app that has a bundle identifier that falls into com.YourName.